# ListView not ordering properly

Tags: java, android, listview, collections, compare

I am creating an app where the user inputs their GPA, SAT, and ACT scores and majors which they are interested in, and the app lists colleges in order based on how closely they match the scores the user entered, and if that college is good at the majors selected. The colleges go from the best match to worst. I got them to order properly when only the numerical scores were entered, but now I would like for the selected majors to factor in. If the user selects a major and the college is good at that major (I made boolean variables for each major) then those colleges should come before the colleges which are not good at the majors selected by the user. This means that the majors are looked at before the scores. Right now the majors don't seem to be factoring in at all.

MajorsList

```
public class ListOfMajors extends Activity {
    public static boolean aerospace, agricultural, biomed, chem, civil, computer, electrical, physics, environment, industrial, materials, mechanical;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.majorslist);
        ListView mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.majorslist);
        String[] list={"Aerospace Engineering","Agricultural Engineering","Biomedical Engineering","Chemical Engineering","Civil Engineering",
                        "Computer Engineering","Electrical Engineering","Engineering Physics","Environmental Engineering","Industrial Engineering",
                        "Materials Engineering","Mechanical Engineering"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListOfMajors.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,list);
        mylist.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        mylist.setAdapter(adapter);

        SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = mylist.getCheckedItemPositions();
        if (checkedItems!= null){
            for(int i=0; i<checkedItems.size();i++){
                if(checkedItems.valueAt(0)){
                    aerospace = true;
                }
                if(checkedItems.valueAt(1)){
                    agricultural = true;
                }
                if(checkedItems.valueAt(2)){
                    biomed = true;
                }
                if(checkedItems.valueAt(3)){
                    chem = true;
                }
                if(checkedItems.valueAt(4)){
                    civil = true;
                }
                if(checkedItems.valueAt(5)){
                    computer = true;
                }
                if(checkedItems.valueAt(6)){
                    electrical = true;
                }
                if(checkedItems.valueAt(7)){
                    physics = true;
                }
                if(checkedItems.valueAt(8)){
                    environment = true;
                }
                if(checkedItems.valueAt(9)){
                    industrial = true;
                }
                if(checkedItems.valueAt(10)){
                    materials = true;
                }
                if(checkedItems.valueAt(11)){
                    mechanical = true;
                }
            }
        }

    }


}
```

CollegeList

```
private class CollegeItem {
private double gpa;
private int act;
private int sat;
private String name;
private String location;
private double score;
private double scoreDistance;
private double majorsDistance;
private boolean uaero, uagri, ubio, uchem, ucivil, ucomp, uelec, uphys, uenvi, uindus, umate, umech;

public CollegeItem(double gpa, int act, int sat, String name, String location, boolean uaero, boolean uagri, boolean ubio, boolean uchem,
                    boolean ucivil, boolean ucomp, boolean uelec, boolean uphys, boolean uenvi, boolean uindus, boolean umate, boolean umech){
    this.gpa = gpa;
    this.act = act;
    this.sat = sat;
    this.name = name;
    this.location = location;
    this.uaero = uaero;
    this.uagri = uagri;
    this.ubio = ubio;
    this.uchem = uchem;
    this.ucivil = ucivil;
    this.ucomp = ucomp;
    this.uelec = uelec;
    this.uphys = uphys;
    this.uenvi = uenvi;
    this.uindus = uindus;
    this.umate = umate;
    this.umech = umech;

    if(act/36.0>sat/2400.0){
        this.score = 0.6*gpa*25.0+0.4*(act/36.0)*100.0;
    }else{
        this.score = 0.6*gpa*25.0+0.4*(sat/2400.0)*100.0;
    }
    this.scoreDistance = Math.abs(this.score-MainActivity.scoreDouble)/MainActivity.scoreDouble;
    if(uaero&&ListOfMajors.aerospace){
        majorsDistance = 0;
    }
}
public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}
public double getScoreDistance(){
    return this.scoreDistance;
}
public double getMajorsDistance(){
    return this.majorsDistance;
}
public class CollegeList extends ListActivity {

ArrayList<CollegeItem> collegeLists=new ArrayList<CollegeItem>();
ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();

Comparator<CollegeItem> compare = new Comparator<CollegeItem>(){
    public int compare(CollegeItem a, CollegeItem b){
        int result = Double.compare(a.getMajorsDistance(), b.getMajorsDistance());
        if(result==0){
            result = Double.compare(a.getScoreDistance(), b.getScoreDistance());
        }
        return result;
    }
};


CollegeItem michigan = new CollegeItem(3.79,30,2020,"University of Michigan","Ann Arbor, Michigan",true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false);
CollegeItem berkeley = new CollegeItem(3.84,30,2040,"University of California Berkeley","Berkeley, California",false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false);
CollegeItem stanford = new CollegeItem(3.96,33,2215,"Stanford University","Stanford, California",false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    collegeLists.add(michigan);
    collegeLists.add(berkeley);
    collegeLists.add(stanford); 

    Collections.sort(collegeLists, compare);

    for(CollegeItem collegeList : collegeLists){
        nameList.add(collegeList.getName());
    }

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(CollegeList.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nameList));



}
```

When I check the first major (aerospace), regardless of the numbers I enter, I would want Michigan to be first college in the list because it has a true value for that major. But as of now, it is not coming first. I believe that either I am comparing the objects wrong or the majors which are selected aren't being registered. Either way, what should I do to get my application working?

Answer (score 0):

While adding element to the list mention position of the element. Only this can order the list in proper order.

Format:    **list.add(position, item);**

---

Example.   **collegeLists.add(1, michigan);**

Comment: Yes. If you want list in proper order then you must have to add position for the elements.

Comment: @Ash Thanks for the response, but the order or elements would change depending on the values entered and boxes checked. I don't think I would be able to use this method to do that.

Comment: where is your onClick method or onChecked method where you sort the list elements at runtime?

Comment: @Ash It isn't on an onClick method, it is sorted with the comparator in the CollegeList class

Comment: As per the logic comparator is called from only onCreate() method means it will set list only when the first time Activity loads. Is this the right condition which you expect or you need to reload the same list automatically?

Comment: Is the comparator returns the proper results?

Comment: The comparator right now sets the order only based off of the scoreDistance variable when I need it to also factor majorsDistance.

Comment: Means comparator not return the items in proper sort order?

Comment: I think the sort is working fine but it shows ascending order right?

Comment: If two corresponding boolean values are both true, I set the variable majorsDistance to 0 so that all colleges that have that value as true will show up before those that do not. Within the ones that are true, it should go in ascending order of the variable scoreDistance. Right now the majorsDistance part doesn't seem to be working